# How to shift a background image with css

Tags: css, background-image

I wanted to put a border around a table which has a background image. The border works fine, but when I do this (it is an 8px border) the background image gets cut off by the border. Am I able to shift the background image to start 8px to the right and 8px down?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the background-position:

```
background-position: 8px 8px;
```

More on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 20):

you could also use some short hand.
`background: <colour> <image url> <repeat> <left> <top> <scroll>`

for yours i'd be thinking something like:
`background : transparent url(<location to img>) no-repeat 8px 8px scroll;`

Comment: To be precise, the background-position first takes an xpos, than a ypos. Thus it's <left> <top>, not <top> <left>.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually shifting the image by `8px`, you should just anchor the image to the padding box (*green* in the diagram below) instead of the border box (*yellow*).  Doing this will place the top-left corner of the image inside of the border instead of behind it.

```
background-origin: padding-box;
```

This will make maintenance easier since it will still work even if you change the border width.

[image: box model]

You can also set the background's origin to the content box (*blue*):

```
background-origin: content-box;
```

[Documentation / Simple Demo @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin)