# Div with background cover

Tags: background, css

I need a semi-full page background image div (like twitter homepage). 
Actually I'm trying with :

```
`background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;`
```

but i need space for the header, like 150-200px height.
How can i fix it? 
I don't want this div behind the header, i want it down from it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if shifting the background image helps you!
[How to shift a background image with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175557/how-to-shift-a-background-image-with-css)

Otherwise, I'd have a div after the header, and put the background image in there. So your HTML code would look like this...

```
<h1>Hi, this is a header!</h1>
<div class="backgroundPlz"></div>
```